# Optimising the Sieve of Eratosthenes using alternative to `forM_`

Tags: haskell, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I've been implementing the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) both in C++ and Haskell. Currently to calculate the number of primes less than one billion, the C++ version runs in 12 seconds, and the Haskell version in 24 seconds.

I was quite impressed at how Haskell was well in the ballpark of C++, but I wanted to see if I could squeeze some more performance out of it.

The algorithm I'm using is fairly simple, a boolean represents every *odd* number three or greater. I skip the evens. Hence there's some fancy math to translate indexes. I know that despite this it's cache performance is horrible but it's just an exercise in comparison not so much performance. Anyway the [code](http://ideone.com/0vbJBB) is below:

```
sieve :: (Ix a, Integral a) => a -> UArray a Bool
sieve n = runSTUArray $ do
  let aLen = n `div` 2 - 1
  let last_test_i = (integralSqrt (aLen*2+1) - 1) `div` 2
  a <- newArray (0, aLen - 1) False
  forM_ [0..(last_test_i)-1] $ \i -> do
    isComp <- readArray a i
    when (not isComp) $ do
      let first = 2*i*(3+i) + 3
      let step = i*2 + 3
      forM_ [first, first + step .. (aLen-1)] $ \j ->
        writeArray a j True
  return a
```

I then thought that maybe the list generation in `forM_` is slowing things down. So I wrote the following function:

```
myForM_ :: (Monad m) => a -> (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> (a -> m b) -> m ()
myForM_ initV fCont fNext f = myForM_W initV
  where myForM_W x = if fCont x then f x >> myForM_W (fNext x) else return ()
```

This is pretty much a copy of an old style C for loop. First argument is initial value, second condition, third is what determines the next value, and the last is the action, or in C the body of the function.

I then replaced `forM_` with `myForM_` like so:

```
sieve :: (Ix a, Integral a) => a -> UArray a Bool
sieve n = runSTUArray $ do
  let aLen = n `div` 2 - 1
  let last_test_i = (integralSqrt (aLen*2+1) - 1) `div` 2
  a <- newArray (0, aLen - 1) False
  --forM_ [0..(last_test_i)-1] $ \i -> do
  myForM_ 0 (/= last_test_i) (+1) $ \i -> do
    isComp <- readArray a i
    when (not isComp) $ do
      let first = 2*i*(3+i) + 3
      let step = i*2 + 3
      --forM_ [first, first + step .. (aLen-1)] $ \j ->
      myForM_ first (< aLen) (+step) $ \j ->
        writeArray a j True
  return a
```

This resulted in execution time going from 24 seconds to 17 seconds, taking more than half the difference between the Haskell version and the C++ version.

I looked for a pre-built version of `myForM_` but I couldn't find one. Am I reinventing the wheel or is this a non-standard approach?

Comment: I find that when I need to write a complex loop (and especially if I want good performance) I just write a helper function, and in general these helper functions can't be easily abstracted into something simple to use. As an aside, you may be able to squeeze out a bit more performance by using unboxed Vector instead of UArray.

Comment: are these timings on ideone, or on your box?

Comment: My box. The ideone timings between the two haskell versions are similarly different, but you'll have to try smaller numbers or ideone will time out.

Comment: I have no idea about Haskell but a few general observations about the sieve. First, the C++ version shouldn't take more than one about a second to sieve 10^9 numbers. Second, the starting index for crossing out ('first') in your code) is normally the square of the current prime, since all lower multiples of the prime have already been eliminated. Not knowing Haskell I don't know for sure but it seems you are skipping the evens instead of leaving them out of the array altogether. This is important since the sieve is normally cache-bound; sieving in 256 KB blocks can double or triple performance

Comment: To make a long story short, you have to be crystal-clear about your algorithm before you start farting around with peripheral optimisations that are the equivalent of dropping into assembler. Your messy index math seems to indicate that there is a lot of room for optimisation - in the sense of making the code smaller, cleaner and meaner, by a deeper understanding of how it works and by discovering its own innate elegance. Then drop the bomb on it with optimisations (which always make the code more complex and much uglier).

Comment: Sorry, just discovered that 'first' does have the square in it, hidden in plain sight. The dang site didn't let me edit the comment. Mea culpa. BTW, have you verified the output against a reliable reference?

Comment: @DarthGizka: You're missing the point. I've made it quite clear in the question that the algorithm is ordinary. It's not about how to best seive. The question is about the poor performance of `forM_` and whether there's a prebuilt alternative like `myForM_`.

Comment: Sorry, you did tag this with "sieve-of-eratosthenes" as well and so I thought you'd be interested in the best way to formulate the sieve in Haskell. So it's only `myForM_` that bugs you? That reminds me of a guy who optimised a sieve by keeping all low primes in registers (a.k.a. [Sieve of Smith](http://zsmith.co/primes.html)), by which feat he was able to sieve the first 2^32 numbers in less than 1.5 hours... :^)

Comment: Probably shouldn't have included that sieve tag sorry.

Comment: No harm done. It's unfortunate that I don't know Haskell because I like the kind of thing you're doing - pushing the limits of a language and thus gaining a deeper understanding. I enjoy the same kind of puzzles just that my Haskells are called FoxPro and C++.

Comment: In any case your code can run even faster than it is now if you reduce the memory footprint by removing the even numbers from the array, simplify index arithmetic by starting the array at 1 instead of 3, and do the sieving in small blocks that fit into the CPU's L2 cache. On my aging Lynnfield (in C++) thats 8.2 s 'classic', 5.5 s packed, 4.2 s classic sieved in 256 KByte blocks, 2.5 s packed 256 KB. Since your code is very tight and fast already, it would show speedups of similar magnitude. If `myForM_` makes an appreciable difference then that would show more clearly with the faster sieve.

Comment: To put it the other way around: you cannot gauge the effect of `myForM_` accurately if your code is actually slowed down by running afoul of your computer's memory system.

Comment: if you're still [interested](http://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=(Monad%20m)%20%3D%3E%20a%20-%3E%20(a%20-%3E%20Bool)%20-%3E%20(a%20-%3E%20a)%20-%3E%20(a%20-%3E%20m%20b)%20-%3E%20m%20())...